# Import .gpx data to PostGIS using ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, gdal, gpx

I want to import a few .gpx files to postgresql using ogr2ogr.
The data in each .gpx looks like this:

```
<trkpt lat="41.842607000" lon="12.490628000"><ele>40.5</ele><time>2010-05-31T14:12:11Z</time> </trkpt>
```

Firstly, I create a new table in postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE test (
           fid serial NOT NULL, --
           geom geometry(Point,4326), 
           ele double precision, 
           "time" timestamp with time zone, 
           CONSTRAINT activities_pk PRIMARY KEY (fid)
);
```

Then when I run the ogr2ogr script:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -f "PostgreSQL"  PG:"host="xx" user="xx" dbname="xx" password="xx"" 1st.gpx  -nln test
```

However, the script failed due to geometry type mismatch.

> Warning 1: Geometry to be inserted is of type Multi Line String,
> whereas the layer geometry type is Point. Insertion is likely to fail
> ERROR 1: ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiLineString) does not match column
> type (Point)
>
> ERROR 1: INSERT command for new feature failed. ERROR:  Geometry type
> (MultiLineString) does not match column type (Point)

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Think you will need to specify a sub dataset in the gpx file, like track, or track points...

Comment: well, it does make sense. But how can I specify a sub dataset? There is only lat/lon in the .pgx file.@nmtoken

Comment: what happens if you create a geometric field with MultiLineString type? geom geometry(MultiLineString,4326),This problem is indicated by the error description...

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko hahah, then I get a similar ERROR: Geometry type (Point) does not match column type (MultiLineString).

Comment: что произойдет, если вы создадите геометрическое поле с типом MultiPoint?

Comment: Have you found the documentation of the GDAL gpx driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpx.html? There are some examples which could be useful. Ogr2ogr can also take care of the creation of the tables so you do not need to do it.

Comment: What does `ogrinfo -so 1st.gpx` give you?  I expect `1: waypoints (Point), 2: routes (Line String), 3: tracks (Multi Line String), 4: route_points (Point), 5: track_points (Point)`

Comment: If so you will want to use ... `1st.gpx track_points...` in your ogr2ogr, for example I use the following to add gpx points to a GeoPackage `ogr2ogr -f GPKG /home/hxxxx/gidataL/GPS/gpsmap64_tracker.gpkg /home/hxxxx/testing/TRACKS/Tracks-toMay7th.gpx track_points -t_srs epsg:27700 -nln Tracks-toMay7th_PTS -update`

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko большое спасибо

Comment: The most important thing is that you found the right solution for your question...:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, everyone for the hints.

After poring over the documentation here
https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpx.html

I realise that the .gpx file contains either points(track_points) or lines(tracks) geometry type. I fix the error by adding a SQL query, which explicitly import points only.

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -f "PostgreSQL"  PG:"host="xx" user="xx" dbname="xx" password="xx"" 1st.gpx  -nln test -sql "Select * From track_points"
```